# IntelliJ does not open from terminal

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, terminal

I have seen in some tutorials where an existing Maven project can be opened in IntelliJ from terminal. (`open terminal; cd < folder containing pom.xml >; idea pom.xml`)

When I do this I am getting the following error:

> The file /private/var/folders/vx/g0dkgs9s7wg7bz8q3yplhwxh0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/A27A814D-1A7C-45BB-88E0-E2ACCA590517/d/IntelliJ IDEA.app does not exist.

I am using macOS High Sierra 10.13.2.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but no luck.

Can somebody help me figure out what the problem is?

Comment: What is the output for `which idea` command in terminal? Make sure to create command line launcher for IDE (Tools | Create Command-line Launcher... action. Then try to run `idea` command form terminal.

Comment: output for *which idea* is :  /usr/local/bin/idea

Comment: Works fine for me when I execute `idea pom.xml`. What is the exact command? Can you open any other projects with `idea` command? Try rebooting the pc.

Comment: nope still doesn't work

Comment: File an issue at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new with steps to reproduce and [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085) attached after IDE restart and reproducing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is how Intellij behaves. I did the following:

1. I started Intellij by clicking on the launcher icon.
2. I got the following screen.[image]
3. Now, in a terminal I navigated to the project directory and did ***idea pom.xml*** . This opened up the project

Without launching Intellij if I try ***idea pom.xml*** from terminal, I am getting this error:

> The file
>   /private/var/folders/vx/g0dkgs9s7wg7bz8q3yplhwxh0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/A27A814D-1A7C-45BB-88E0-E2ACCA590517/d/IntelliJ
>   IDEA.app does not exist.

Comment: This is not a response to the issue. Why you post this again here?

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me from time to time when upgrade to a new version of IntelliJ or when upgrade my OS (Mojave). These are the steps that I did to fix it in macOS:

- check where the executable is located: `which idea` (probably will be
  `/usr/local/bin/idea`)
- I'm getting a `Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/182.4129.33/IntelliJ
  IDEA.app does not exist.` error so I lookup into the ch-0 folder and
  get `182.5107.16  183.4284.148`. This is the issue, Intellij is still
  pointing to a previous version which does not exist.
- Opening the idea executable in step 1 and check the following section

  RUN_PATH = u'/Users/robertomoreno/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/182.4129.33/IntelliJ IDEA.app'
  CONFIG_PATH = u'/Users/robertomoreno/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2018.2'
  SYSTEM_PATH = u'/Users/robertomoreno/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2018.2'
- Change it with the proper version:

  RUN_PATH = u'/Users/robertomoreno/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/183.4284.148/IntelliJ IDEA.app'
  CONFIG_PATH = u'/Users/robertomoreno/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2018.3'
  SYSTEM_PATH = u'/Users/robertomoreno/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2018.3'
- `idea path/to/file.is` should work now

Answer (score 4):

Simpler solution.

You need to recreate the CLI scripts from within the tool/application. Probably you update IntelliJ and still pointing to non-existing version 
>

> /private/var/folders/vx/g0dkgs9s7wg7bz8q3yplhwxh0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/A27A814D-1A7C-45BB-88E0-E2ACCA590517 .....

In IntelliJ running go to Tools -> Tools -> Create Command Line Launcher...,
The file '/usr/local/bin/idea' already exists Would you like to overwrite it?
Open a new console and should work.